# move HTML elements

Tags: html, css, move

I try to move Html elements inside the body, but I can't figure out how for example I want to have 
form tag in the middle of the browser (there has to be only form tag nothing else) and I can't figure out how to do it can Anyone help me and suggest me what topics should I read to find out at last how to move html elements (maybe link some articles where could I read it)

Comment: Did you do a google search for this? Anyways, check this http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-positioning-19970819

Comment: Maybe you start clarifying what you understand when saying "move". Do you mean a drag and drop interaction or just moving the form element in DOM to another parent element?

Comment: Do you want to position it in the middle of the page and stay there or  you want to move it while the user is on this page ?

Comment: I Just want to put the form tag in the middle of the browser nothing more when I create tag It puts not in the middle but in the top at left corner so i want to move it

Comment: Create a http://jsfiddle.net/ document, post the link here and we will do it quickly for you

Comment: Your question is very vague, please elaborate on what exactly you want to achieve by give examples.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7z6N5/ here is the link so i want that this form to be in the middle of the page not at the top

Comment: Place the link to your jsfiddle into your querstion. Also place some code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments I assume that you are talking about centering your form.

Create your form, for example

```
<div id="formContainer">
    // Your form will go here.
</div>
```

Then specify some CSS that will center the form

```
#formContainer
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px; // Should be -(width/2).
    margin-top: -100px; // Should be -(height/2).
 }
```

This will place your form in the middle of the HTML page.